# Pandas: Adding x number of Columns together based on value (x) in another column

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Test dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,2,2,], 'B':[2,2,2], 'C':[2,2,2], 'Fields':[3,2,1]})
```

I need to add the values of 'A', 'B', and 'C' together based on the value in each row of the 'Fields' column. If the number of 'Fields' = 3, return C.  If the number of 'Fields' is 2, add only B, C. If the number of 'Fields' is 1, add A, B, and C. The output I am looking for is:

```
df_correct = pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,2,2,], 'B':[2,2,2], 'C':[2,2,2], 'Fields':[3,2,1],'NewColumn':[2,4,6])
```

I'd like to avoid if else statements and instead do something by indexing columns. The Excel Solution that has worked (per row, assuming the columns are A-D): E1=SUM(OFFSET(A1,0,(D1-1)):C1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda r: r[r['Fields']-1:3].sum(), axis=1)
0    2
1    4
2    6
dtype: int64
```